# Change format of 'timing show' or 'set timing on' in sqlplus (to increase precision)

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I found useful such setting:

```
set timing on;
```

or such coding technique:

```
timing start;
select ...;
timing stop;
```

But it output uses a few digits for second fractional part:

```
Затрач.время: 00:00:00.02
```

Is that possible to adjust output format of **timing** in Sql*PLUS?

I want to add more digits to fractional part, like for timestamps:

```
alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'MI:SS.FF6';
```

**PS** I use

```
select LAST_LOAD_TIME, ELAPSED_TIME, MODULE, SQL_TEXT elasped from v$sql
  order by LAST_LOAD_TIME desc
```

for high precision timing (microseconds) but it is inconvenient especially for PL/SQL.

Comment: If you need timing to be that accurate I'd suggest looking at wait event tracing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think it is possible.

DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME also gives you the information in 100th's of a second.

> GET_TIME Function
>
> This function determines the current time in 100th's of a second. (...)

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#i1002765

(Oracle Database PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference)

Comment: TKPROF formats it to 2 decimal places, but trace files measure to the microsecond.  See page 9 of [this SQL Trace presentation](http://method-r.com/downloads/doc_view/72-mastering-performance-with-extended-sql-trace?tmpl=component&format=raw).  But I agree it's not possible with `timing`.  According to [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2699400) "The format of timing statistics is dependent on the operating system. In Linux and Windows, the timing statistics are in 24 hour format displaying hours, minutes, seconds and hundredths of seconds".

Comment: @jonearles Hi, I knew it is up to microseconds but I did not found proof for it in the documentation. I will remove this part from the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @jonearles thanks for link to official docs! I don't expect to find this info so read docs between lines...